# Training a CNN on temporal image data

Tags: conv-neural-network, temporal

I am working on a project where I have 1024x1024 brain images over time depicting blood flow. A blood flow parameter image is computed using the brain images over time, and is off the same dimension (1024 x 1024). My goal is to train a CNN to learn the mapping between the brain images over time and the blood flow parameter image.

I've looked into current CNN architectures, but it seems like most research on CNNs is either done for classification on single images (not images over time) or action recognition on video data, which I'm not sure my problem falls under. If anyone can provide me with any insight or papers I can read on how to train a model on temporal data, with the output being an image (rather than a classification score), that would be immensely helpful.

Comment: For something more abstract (given that you appear to be asking for research resources, rather than say libs or implementations), you may do better on https://stats.stackexchange.com/. Also, simplifying your end goal of "...learn the mapping between the brain images over time and the blood flow parameter image" to be less domain specific may help others answer your question better. For my off-the-cuff, 2 cents on your problem at hand, when hearing anything over-time, I think RNN (eg. you could get HOG processed *snapshots* of the images and load as samples for an RNN for each brain video(?)).

Comment: I''l repost my question there thanks! I'll also look into RNN implementations, I appreciate the help :)